# Some part of fork() mechanism

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork

Upon reading "Linux Kernel Development" I saw next statetement:

> Traditionally, upon `fork()`, all resources owned by the parent are duplicated and the
>   copy is given to the child.This approach is naive and inefficient in that it copies much
>   data that might otherwise be shared.Worse still, if the new process were to immediately
>   execute a new image, all that copying would go to waste

Why do `fork()` need to copy all parent's resources? Why we can't simply allot freshly new chunk of space for all resources needed by new process? Why is there neediness in copying? And the last query - if the new process were to immediately execute the new image, why would that copying go to waste?

Comment: For some time there was a variation of fork() called vfork(), http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/vfork.html, which did not copy the resources. It was meant to be used in cases when the form was followed by exec(). The problem was, what to do if the exec() call failed? The child process had no resources (memory, filedescriptors) of its own to do error reporting or error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why we can't simply allot freshly new chunk of space for all resources
>   needed by new process

The semantics of `forks(2)` say that when you do it another process starts executing **from that point**. So if it starts executing, it will naturally have some expectations regarding declared variables, their values and so on. You need to copy everything* the parent had access to.

```
int x = 42;
fork();
if (parent)
    /* x == 42. */
else
    /* I can haz x ? */
```

> if the new process were to immediately execute the new image, why would that copying go
>   to waste

This copying is completely useless if the new process turns out not to need continue from that point. For example, if the new process simply wants to start executing a new program, it won't need any of those variables mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that inefficiency is not such inefficient. AFAIK, `fork()` performs a **copy-on-write**. This mechanism makes memory to be copied only if the child process attempts to write it. So, `x` won't be copied if the child process doesn't write to it, yet it can access the variable for reading. Writing attempts are normally detected by a piece of hardware called "Memory Management Unit".

On the other hand, there are applications in which it is very useful to inherit a status variable from a child process, so "cleaning" the memory space would not be useful in such case.

Answer (score 1):

In case when we are not executing a new image like in the cases where we use pipes then copying of all the parents resources is very important. When they implemented fork() it should be generic no matter how the programmer uses it.So copying parents resources makes sense.